# Rotate SurfaceView when capturing from Camera

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview

I'm trying to create simple camera app. I use SurfaceView in my layout and obtain camera in a standard way, like in camera tutorial on android.developer.com. But I have flipped and stretched picture in result. I've tried to set orientation to portrait in camera parameters and setDisplayOrientation(0) but it does not helps me.

[image: SurfaceView]

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is issue on 2.1. And in 2.2 and later version have useful method setDisplayOrientation to fix this problem.